# Is that possible to get facial expression information like animojis via CoreML or ARkit?

Tags: ios, computer-vision, human-computer-interface

As Apple shown yesterday, the Animoji is amazingly retarget human facial movement to emojis,

so is it possible for us to use something like the picture below via CoreML or ARkit?
[image]